# Image texture on Obj drone file?

Tags: texturing, materials, obj

I have generated an Obj file from a drone surveying (using DroneDeploy). When I import it to Blender it has materials and textures attached to it. I want to change the areal photo (taken by the drone, and now used as texture) to an image texture that I created in Photoshop. I removed all materials and created a new with an Image Texture as Base Color. But the image gets all scattered and misplaced. See attached image.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to change the areal photo-texture to an image texture."? Do you mean you want to change one image texture to another? Could you edit the question and show us how the textures in question look?

Comment: Yes, I want to replace the current texture, which is the aerial image from the drone, with an image created in Photoshop.

Comment: The current texture and materials are created automatically during the Obj export from the drone program. And it seems that it's positions is handled by code in both the .obj and .mtl-files (when I look at these files in a text-editor)

Comment: Look into UV mapping. You can unwrap or project another UV map that would be more suitable for "handmade" textures .

Comment: Ah, ok. Kind of wanted to handle it "automatically", need to do this in several projects so won't be able to do it "by hand" :(

Comment: You could provide more information about the issue if you want to get a proper answer. A lot of things can be automated in Blender, but at the moment it is hard to understand what you want to do and why. If you describe it in detail providing examples of generated textures and the ones you want to use instead, some example mesh and describe the full context, it is possible someone might be able to help...